# Calculate integral of $\ln(z)$ using the residue theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Please is it possible to calculate $\int_{C(0,1)}\ln(z)\,dz$ using the residue theorem?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The function $\ln z$ is not meromorphic on any open set containing the circle $\{|z|\le1\}$. $z=0$ is a branching point.

Comment: Ok got it , thank you so much :)